# Why CodeMirror JavaScript is not defined Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, codemirror

I didn't find the answer of this error here.

I have a Ruby on Rails website and I want to add code editor like CodeMirror.

The first thing I did is to add `codemirror.js` inside `assets/javascript` folder. Second I added `codemirror.css` inside `assets/stylesheets`:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>xxxxx</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <link  type="text/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/codemirror.css">
    <script type="text/javacsript" src="/assets/javascripts/codemirror.js" > </script>
    <script type="text/javacsript" src="mode/javascripts/javascript.js"></script>
  </head>
```

I added this JavaScript code to my textfield

```
<%= form_for [@unit, @attempt] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "editor"%>
    <%= f.submit "Run"%>
  <% end %>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var code = $(".editor")[0];
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code,{
      lineNumbers : true
    })
   })
  </script>
```

then I got these errors inside the console

```
jquery-3.3.1.js:3827 Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (9:88)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.3.1.js:3534)
    at process (jquery-3.3.1.js:3602)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like it isn't finding the files.  Are all those files really inside a `units` directory?

Comment: @RockwellRice no it's not! just the text area with this <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var code = $(".editor")[0];
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code,{
      lineNumbers : true
    })
   })
  </script>

Comment: Ya so I guess fix that path it is using to try to find those files and it should work

Comment: I fix it but i still got the same error

Comment: Can you post the layout file?  Is that script being called before the codemirror js is being included into the file?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am facing similar issue and I have posted it here: stackoverflow.com/q/69430941/7584240 If you get a chance can you please have a look and provide some resolution.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html doc you need to add codemirror.js as well.

`<script src="lib/codemirror.js"></script>`

you added jquery twice not the codemirror.js

If you added codeirror.js then you should check network tab in browser. Is there any 404 for codemirror.js?
If yes then you should use correct path for the codemirror.js.
1 more thing you should add `<script> your code</script>` code after the `<script src="codemirror.js"></script>` file.

#### updates

create a file `/mode/javascripts/custom.js`

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var code = $(".editor")[0];
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code,{
      lineNumbers : true
    })
   })
```

Import your file in main layout file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>xxxxx</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <link  type="text/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/codemirror.css">
    <script type="text/javacsript" src="/assets/javascripts/codemirror.js" > </script>
    <script type="text/javacsript" src="/mode/javascripts/javascript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javacsript" src="/mode/javascripts/custom.js"></script>
  </head>
...
</html>
```

your ERB file

```rb
<%= form_for [@unit, @attempt] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "editor"%>
    <%= f.submit "Run"%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I add it like this <script type="text/javacsript" src="codemirror.js"></script>  but not sure how can i correct the path because i got the same error

Comment: in the network tab of the browser is there any status 404 for codemirror.js?

Comment: This means you are using a different path. 
in rails you should use `<script src="/assets/javascript/codemirror.js" > </script>`

Comment: the same error jquery-3.3.1.js:3827 Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined

Comment: the file under app -> assets -> javascripts -> codemirror.js

Comment: Add your custom code in the file. (that you wrote in a script tag). Include that file after adding the code mirror javascript files.

Comment: I updated the answer. Hoping it would help.

Comment: Unfortunately Im still getting the same error

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am facing similar issue and I have posted it here: stackoverflow.com/q/69430941/7584240 If you get a chance can you please have a look and provide some resolution.